# Wirecard Elastic Engine notification error with payments

Tags: php, payment, wirecard

We are trying to implement the new Wirecard Elastic Engine payment gateway with our existing website which is in PHP CodeIgniter.

Currently, we are also integrating it into an iOS app.
We have a problem with the notification aspect while making a payment.
When a payment is initiated in the iOS app, we are supposed to provide a URL that the Wirecard engine can notify which will be read from the PHP code.

We have a controller in the backend and we provide it to Wirecard each time with a unique hash code.
At this point, Wirecard is supposed to send a response to this URL. We are having trouble reading the response.
We have tried a couple of solutions
1. file_get_contents
2. cURL connection

Each time, we get an empty response, even though the Wirecard reps say that the response went through.
Please help!

Comment: Which payment method?

Comment: @Kajzer deposits using a credit card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the payment-sdk examples. [Choose examples from the right menu](https://github.com/wirecard/paymentSDK-php/wiki) I hope it will help you. If not, create an issue there and I will look into your problem.